# Liferay and <portlet:renderURL> to a friendly URL

Tags: href, liferay-6, portlet

I have created a page with a friendly URL of /balance-inquiries.  The full URL given within the Liferay Admin's Site Pages page is http://localhost:8080/group/guest/balance-inquiries.

Creating a renderUrl (or an actionUrl) to this page, from another page is proving to be a bit frustrating.  Below is one of many variations I have tried to get this working.

```
<portlet:renderURL var="searchTransactionsUrl">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/balance-inquiries" />
</portlet:renderURL>
<a href="<%=searchTransactionsUrl%>">Search LPC Transactions</a>
```

My question is what param values should I use to make this link work?  Or should I resort to a redirect, or using  instead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out how to build dynamic URLs for portlets spanning different WAR files.  The code is as follows:

```
<portlet:defineObjects />
<liferay-theme:defineObjects />

<%
    String portletId = "giftcardtransactionfilesummary_WAR_myportalgiftcardportlet";
    long otherPlid = PortalUtil.getPlidFromPortletId(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), portletId);
%>

<liferay-portlet:renderURL var="giftcardTransactionFileSummaryUrl" plid="<%=otherPlid%>" portletName="<%=portletId%>">
    <liferay-portlet:param name="groupId" value="10157" />
    <liferay-portlet:param name="articleId" value="11385" />
</liferay-portlet:renderURL>

<a href="<%=giftcardTransactionFileSummaryUrl%>">view giftcard batch files</a>
```

The tricks are as follows:

- Understanding the naming convention behind Liferay-generated
  portletIds
- Adding < liferay-theme:defineObjects /> to your page, as
  that injects a value for themeDisplay

Other than that, adding the necessary @page and @taglib directives, and all should work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't create render or action urls to pages, but to portlets.

If you want to pass parameters between portlets on the same page, use [inter portlet communication](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portlet+to+Portlet+Communication).

If you want to redirect to a page with different portlet, make your [portlet configurable](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/implementing-configurable-portlet-prefer-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-03-en) and specify the page url in the portlet preferences. In general, you don't know the page where the target portlet will be placed to. It can be a single page or multiple pages or anything.

If you want to pass parameters to a portlet on a different page, make the page url configurable and pass the parameters through friendly url.

Comment: Thanks for the concise summary.  Your final comment hits upon the crux of my issue: "make the page url configurable and pass the parameters through friendly url".  I'm looking for an example on how this is done via a <portlet:renderURL> tag.  I'm assuming this, or <liferay-portlet:renderURL>, are the appropriate mechanisms?

Comment: I'd like to clarify I am looking for a way to use mvcPath across WAR files, which doesn't seem possible.  That is, everything I've tried seems to require the mvcPath to reference a path to a jsp page within the same WAR file.  I'll be investigating <liferay-portlet:renderUrl> some more, as that allows links to other WAR files... just need to figure out a few more things.